# How to do a custom action when clicking on a file upload button

Tags: 8

In my content type I have a custom widget added to an Image field. I need to open a custom popup when clicking in the image fields 'Choose File' button.

What I actually want to do is change the Image fields behavior like as in Entity Browser. I have created a new widget and added to that Image field, but I have no idea how to change the Choose File button to a button like entity browser.

Comment: You can't, that button is provided by the browser. You need to use a different widget for an entity browser, the file upload is literally just for uploading files

Comment: @Clive yes I have created a widget but I have no idea how to change the field into something different like entity browser

Comment: Why don't you just use the entity browser widget? you'll probably need to explain in a lot more detail what you've done and what you're trying to achieve to get a good answer

Comment: @Clive I need to do something like `image_widget_crop` module. But it doesnt work with entity browser because to work with `image_widget_crop` the field widget needs to be changed. So I have created similar widget. It does what it needs to do when uploading images. But I need an option to select my previously uploaded images. Its written in js. So I need to trigger my js function when clicking on the image fields button.

Comment: Sorry but I doubt anyone's going to be able to understand it from that couple of line description. I'd advise editing the question and providing all the information, code samples, etc, in there